# Trying to append my close button to my new list items but it doesnt seem to be working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to append my close button to my new lists as I fire my addItem button but it doesn't seem to be printing out with each new item pushed to the list, the close button is just bunching up.

I'm also trying to add a bootstrap 'x' icon to my close button but I'm unsure.

Love to get some assistance on this.

```js
let button = document.getElementById('btn');
let list= document.getElementById('item');


button.addEventListener('click', addItem);

// create a new item when the add button is clicked
function addItem(){
    let li= document.createElement('li');
    let newItem= document.getElementById('input').value;
    let x= document.createTextNode(newItem);
    li.appendChild(x);

    if(newItem == ''){
        alert('You have to write something');
    }else{
        document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li)
    }

// add a close button to each item
    var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (let i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  var txt = document.createTextNode(" close");
  para.className = "close";
  para.appendChild(txt);
  myNodelist[i].appendChild(para);
}

// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
for (let i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}
}
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Chango';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/chango/v9/2V0cKI0OB5U7WaJCyHe5.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Mukta';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/mukta/v7/iJWKBXyXfDDVXbnBrXw.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
  }

header{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 200px;
}

h1{
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: Chango, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

h5{
    font-family: Mukta;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;
}

#container{
    position: relative;

    text-align: center;
    top: 220px;
    
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
  }
  
  .close:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
  }

  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
<header>
        <h1>ToDo List</h1>
        <h5>Add items below</h5>
    </header>

    <div id="container">
        <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="e.g. banana">
        <button id="btn">Add Item</button>
        
        <ul id="list">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-x-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M14 1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12zM2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2z"/>
                <path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
              </svg>

        </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: You do not need to close button through the additional for loop, just add with the input's value. that avoid the close duplicate create and append close button to li tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the JS for close button and to align close button with li need to update CSS.

Correction:
You are adding close button with wrong condition.

```js
let button = document.getElementById('btn');
let list= document.getElementById('item');


button.addEventListener('click', addItem);

// create a new item when the add button is clicked
function addItem(){
    let li= document.createElement('li');
    let newItem= document.getElementById('input').value;
    let x= document.createTextNode(newItem);
    li.appendChild(x);

    if(newItem == ''){
        alert('You have to write something');
    }else{
        document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li)
    }

// add a close button to each item
    var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (let i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
// first check if class is already added or not otherwise it will append class again and again
if(myNodelist[i].querySelector('.close') == null) {
var para = document.createElement("span");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("close");
  para.className = "close";
  para.appendChild(txt);
  myNodelist[i].appendChild(para);
}
  
}

// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
for (let i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function() {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}
}
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Chango';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/chango/v9/2V0cKI0OB5U7WaJCyHe5.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Mukta';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/mukta/v7/iJWKBXyXfDDVXbnBrXw.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
  }

header{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 200px;
}

h1{
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: Chango, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

h5{
    font-family: Mukta;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;
}

#container{
    position: relative;

    text-align: center;
    top: 220px;
    
}

.close {
   
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
  }
  li {
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
  }
  .close:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
  }

  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
<header>
        <h1>ToDo List</h1>
        <h5>Add items below</h5>
    </header>

    <div id="container">
        <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="e.g. banana">
        <button id="btn">Add Item</button>
        
        <ul id="list">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-x-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M14 1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12zM2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2z"/>
                <path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
              </svg>

        </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: also, Which bootstrap 'x' button are you trying to add here? you need make same button node for `<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>` and add instead of close text in span node in JS.

Comment: Hi Dhara, all worked.. can you explain the final piece I little more? I'm struggling to add the x icon instead of the close text

Comment: After checking if condition in creating new span and text node, you need to replace all that code with '<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>'. So 1)Create button element for above code with all attributes and create span and its textnode.2) Add span into button tag and add button into li. And it will show you 'x' instead of close